# Display multiple big images in android

Tags: java, android, image, caching, out-of-memory

First of all, as a side-note I tested everything with a Moto G. This should work with lower end devices or even higher end (Like Sony Xperia Tablet Z).

I have an app that, in the menu, displays 3 big images.
Each image takes the full height of the screen and 1/3 of the screen in width. However, when of the images is tapped the other two leave the screen making the selected one occupy 100% of the screen (in both height and width).

So, given this, I have 3 image views and I load the correspondent image to each one.
The images are the exact same screen resolution (1280*720) so I believe I cannot pull any "resize" magic to make them smaller in MB. So everything goes fine when I load the images for the first time and while I keep rotating the device I'll end up in a OutOfMemory Exception (I also have specific images for landscape).

My goal is to be able to display those images without having this exception; but I find it hard because I need three images at the same time having each ~3.5MB (

I tried some methods to reduce the images but hasn't been easy:

- Have a LruCache that saves each image so I is already loaded into memory and reduce time to read from disk. Max size is [3.5 * 6] (size of each image times the number of possible images: landscape + portrait). Also tried having size only for 3 images but the result is the same. This cache is cleared (`evictAll()`) when the `onLowMemory` event is triggered
- In the `onPause` event of the activity I get the `BitmapDrawable` of each `ImageView` and call `recycle()` on it. Still leads to `OutOfMemory` (although less often)

I have two theories that I haven't tried because I don't believe they would help but I'd like to know from you:

- Use a `LruDiskCache`. I saw the implementation of it and the main problem will still remain: having the images in memory
- Use `SoftReference<Bitmap>`. For what I understand the GC won't touch the references if they are loaded into the memory, right? So in this case they will still in memory and will lead to `OutOfMemory`, right? And I already recycle each bitmap during `onPause` so it should be fine, no?

I was considering getting a downscaled version, let's say 75% of the fullscreen, and each image size would end up being ~0.50MB (way less!) but I fear the quality won't be any near the desired.

Comment: Look into [`Picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Much thanks! Didn't know about this framework. Will report with the result

Comment: Sadly... still crashes...

Comment: You will still need to rescale your image. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740307/load-large-images-with-picasso-and-custom-transform-object/23741267#23741267) is a link on how to resize it while keeping the aspect ratio.