# How to solve Out of memory on a 8294416-byte allocation exception?

Tags: android, picasso, heap-memory, android-bitmap

I am making an application to display slideshow of images and videos. I am using ViewFlipper to flip videos and images. Moreover, I am using Picasso library to display image from local storage. Now, when I try to run the application at some point it is running perfectly. But once in a while, I a getting the exception Out of memory on a 8294416-byte allocation. I googled it and find one solution that using "android:largeHeap=true" I could solve the issue. But it didn't worked for me. Do anyone knows how to solve it?

Here is my logcat showing the error :
[image]

Comment: reduce the size of the image

Comment: How can I reduce it? Can you help me with that?

Comment: Make the image smaller (width x height px). What size is the image?

Comment: Any specific reason why you're using a ViewFlipper in stead of a ViewPager?

Comment: @Neil Yes. Actually I have implemented both. But ViewFlipper fits perfectly in my case as I am flipping both images and videos.

Comment: You can do the same with ViewPager using fragments. I think that may also help solve your memory issue. You can also try using Glide to load your resources. Have you ever had the error while trying ViewPager?

Comment: No. When I used ViewPager I have only added 15 images at a time. But now I am adding 62 images at a time and getting the exception.

Comment: The ViewPager recycles the Fragments. You shouldn't get an out of memory issue if you implement it properly. I suggest you switch to ViewPager.

Comment: @Neil Thank you for your suggestion. Is this exception occurs because of ViewFlipper or size of image?

Comment: I would say both. Mainly because of the sheer amount of images you're loading into it. ViewPager will solve your problem. Don't think the ViewFlipper recycles views.

Comment: @Neil Ok. I will try to implement with ViewPager. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good training to load large Bitmaps in Android

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

**Edit**
This is another SO answer which is related to Picasso.
Look at .resize(width, height)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23741267/1723525

Comment: Thanks. I will go through it. But there are different images in which I am getting this exception.

Comment: @Dhaval I have added another SO answer which will help you

Comment: Thanks. I am reviewing that as well.

Comment: Thank you. It is working for now. I will test with more images and figure out what will happen.