# Image does not load into image View from URL

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, image-loading

I am trying to load  this [big size image](http://pir.alphasols.com/Client_Bostwana_BuilderWorld_AndroidApp/PictureFolder/BW%20Jul17%20Mend%20pg5%20COPY-1.png)
into imageview using Picasoo Library and all other library but it does not show. It can load small image but does not laod the above big size image.
please help me how to load heavy image having size  about 1-2Mb.

```
private void setImagesUsingPicasso(final String URL,final ImageView imgVW) 
        {
             String url=URL;
              //Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).fit().centerCrop().into(imgVW);
             profileProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(new Target()
            {

                public void onBitmapLoaded ( Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
                {
                         profileProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    imgVW.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0)
                {
                //Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.powered_by_google_dark);
                //icon=getRoundedRectBitmap(icon, 100);
              // imgVW.setImageBitmap(R);

                //  setImagesUsingPicasso(URL,imgVW);

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) 
                {
                    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.google_map_icon_white);
                    //icon=getRoundedRectBitmap(icon, 100);
                   // imgVW.setImageBitmap(icon);


                }
        });
         }
```

Comment: that image is too large for the device to handle.

Comment: if your image is too large then resize it before loading to in imageview, you can do it like this `Picasso.with(this).load(uri).resize(200, 200).centerInside().into(yourImageView);`

Comment: You should use `.fit()`. WIll crop your image to ImageView actual size. Using a big image can lead to leak memory.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan it does not load the image it can load small image but does not load the image i am trying to load which is about1-2MB

Answer (score 1):

Working fine for me with big images

```
Picasso.with(this).load(/*uri*/).resize(500, 500).centerInside().into(/*ImageView*/);
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: it does not work can not load the image from the url i mentioned. can you please try your self

Comment: @PirFahimShah
works, check the url which you pass to method
`Picasso.with(this).load("http://pir.alphasols.com/Client_Bostwana_BuilderWorld_AndroidApp/PictureFolder/BW%20Jul17%20Mend%20pg5%20COPY-1.png").resize(500, 500).centerInside().into(mReceipt);`

Comment: yes when i pass the url having small image then it can load but does not load the image having size about 1-2MB

Comment: @PirFahimShah I tried with your url and code above was working fine, you tried it?

Comment: then maybe check such issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/23741267/8393260

Answer (score 0):

**you can download image from url using AsyncTask**

**2 .try this if you dont want to use third party library**

```
 new DownloadImage(imamgeview).execute(url);
```

**create a Async Task**

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = (ImageView ) bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
}
```

**i hope that it will work in your case**

**if it not work than i suggest you  Use** `**WebView**` instead `**ImageView**`

Comment: I am trying and let you know, but are you sure it show a picture with 1-2 Mb in imageview.

Comment: than i suggest you  Use `WebView` instead `ImageView`

Comment: yup you can try this

Comment: can your share your image url

Comment: http://pir.alphasols.com/Client_Bostwana_BuilderWorld_AndroidApp/PictureFolder/BW%20Jul17%20Mend%20pg5%20COPY-1.png

Comment: @PirFahimShah because your image size is too high for imageview

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you give Glide a try, it's more memory efficiënt than Picasso, as Picasso loads the full image in memory while Glide loads it resized.

- [Glide vs Picasso - caching](https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d)

Also Glide uses RGB_565 instead of RGB_8888 like Picasso, which does give a slightly less high res image but consumes about 50% less memory, so that's a trade off you might want.

- [Glide vs Picasso - RGB values](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)

Also Glide is used in official google apps, just as FYI.

lastly, you can make the image fit the desired ratios of your imageview and it wont load the full image in it, but a resized version (altough you can also do that in Picasso), like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("your url")
.override(100, 200) //give resize dimension, you could calculate thos
.centerCrop() // scale to fill the ImageView
.into(yourImageView);
```

more info on Glide here: [Glide help](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library)

Hope this helps, let me know if you have other questions. :)

*update*

make sure you imported internet use in the manifest file like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I than made an ImageView as simple as this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

imported Glide in Gradle with this version:

```
compile group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', name: 'glide', version: '3.3.1'
```

and than just used what i said earlier:

```
private void loadImg() {
    ImageView ivTest = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_test);
    String url = "http://pir.alphasols.com/Client_Bostwana_BuilderWorld_AndroidApp/PictureFolder/BW%20Jul17%20Mend%20pg5%20COPY-1.png";
    Log.i("main","loading got called");
    Glide.with(this.getBaseContext())
            .load(url)
            .into(ivTest);
}
```

didn't even use an override and it worked!

Comment: I am getting this error :
The method override(int, int) is undefined for the type RequestBuilder<Drawable>

Comment: Let me implement it myself, i'll get back at you.

Comment: Ok, so it works for me, I will update my answer with more code, one second! :)

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.Pools$SimplePool

Comment: Seems like a problem with your support library and not with what i wrote, have you tried making a test app and only adding this code? to see if the image can load then.